# Stored procedure causes ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure like this

```
UPDATE rv
SET Redeemed = 1,
    DateRedeemed = @DateRedeemed,
    OnlineID = @SaleID
FROM Coupon AS rv
WHERE REPLACE(rv.ID, '-', '') = @RewardID
    AND TypeID = 2;

EXEC [dbo].[spRewardVoucherSearch] @docketNumber = @RewardID
```

spRewardVoucherSearch is this

```
SELECT REPLACE(lv.ID, '-', '') AS Number, "REF" AS Ref, lv.* 
FROM Coupon AS lv 
WHERE REPLACE(lv.ID, '-', '') = @docketNumber
    AND TypeID = 2;
```

now when i run the following code

```
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "spRedeemGiftVoucher"
cmd.NamedParameters = True
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@GiftVoucherID", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 9, UCase(giftVouchers(0,i)))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SerialNo", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 16, UCase(giftVouchers(1,i)))
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@DateRedeemed", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, 20, Now())
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@SaleID", adBigInt, adParamInput, 0, CLng(saleid))
rs.Open cmd
giftValues(i) = rs("Value")
```

i get the following error

> ADODB.Field error '800a0bcd'
>
> Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted. Requested operation requires a current record.

now the page i am running this code from is a checkout processing page, in the previous page i already validate that my voucher existing using `spRewardVoucherSearch` with almost similar code (however it just takes the first parameter) so i know the voucher exists. in the off chance that it may have been deleted from the database an `If rs.EOF Then` which isn't going to help because then the processing is already stuff (the check would just serve to output an error and stop further processing but i can deal with that later)

when i run the first procedure in SQL Management Studio what i get is the result set i would get had i ran `spRewardVoucherSearch` (which is what i desired). since i had ran `spRewardVoucherSearch` on it's own on a previous page and got `rs("Value")` how come i get the error? and is there a way for me to do what i desire to do without getting the error?

Comment: Two things you need to check, First : Have you given output variable in query as alias value because you are using rs("Value"). Second : When query returns result check whether it returns any result or is it null because you need to check for rs.eof or rs.bof before getting the value from recordset.

Comment: @PareshJadhav with the first one are you talking about using `OUTPUT` like `@SaleID int OUTPUT`? if so i don't have that in either procedure and as i have said `spRewardVoucherSearch` worked perfectly fine with the same asp code (only difference is that one i do have an `rs.EOF`) so why would it work with spRewardVoucherSearch without it?

Comment: Where does `@RewardID` come from?

Comment: You'll need to specify `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of your stored procedure or `ADODB` will class row count from your `UPDATE` as a separate closed `ADODB.Recordset`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if recordset if empty or not.

You can code like this:

```
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then 
 giftValues(i) = rs("Value")
Else 
 MsgBox "Recordset is Empty"
End If
```

Comment: However the record does exists, as i have explained `spRewardVoucherSearch` by itself ran previously on another page just fine and i also ran the main procedure with the same arguments and get my record set that `spRewardVoucherSearch` would output, as i expect, or are you saying that `rs("Value")` will always return an error unless i use `rs.EOF` (which i used on the previous page to stop all processing, you can not access the page i'm having problems with if `rs.EOF = true`)

Comment: Yes, your recordset rs may be returning error or may be empty.

Comment: +1 - Nice to see someone using a bit of common there - '800a0bcd' means that either BOF (Beginning of File) or EOF (End of File) are true.  What more can you say?! @Memor-X you need to pipe your query to the screen so you can test it in something like SSMS. Try [Binging it](http://www.bing.com/search?q=%27800a0bcd%27&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=%27800a0bcd%27&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=a02dd7f05aa5497c86869dbc0871208b).

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```vb
'do not use rs.Open cmd  
'Execute the stored procedure instead
SET rs = cmd.Execute
SET cmd = Nothing

'You can now access the record set
if (not rs.EOF) THEN
    'giftValues(i) = rs("Value")
    Response.Write rs("Value")'print it
end if

'dispose your objects
rs.Close
SET rs = Nothing

conn.Close
SET conn = Nothing
```

Comment: Needs a BOF as well ... just in case!